# .net web api caching

Tags: c#, caching, webapi

I have created a CacheFilter

```
public class CacheFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public int TimeDurationInSecs { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
        {
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeDurationInSecs),
            MustRevalidate = true,
            Public = true
        };
    }
}
```

I have a web api method decorated with cache filter

```
[CacheFilter(TimeDurationInSecs =100)]
    public Guid GetGuid()
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid();
    }
```

I expect the call to GetGuid return me same Guid for every request made in 100 seconds.
But i get a new Guid every time i refresh the page...

Am i missing something?

Comment: If you add a `Cache-Control` header it's up to clients (and potentially proxies) to respect it; it won't change the behaviour or your API beyond that.  Are you sure your client is doing so?

Comment: Thanks sellotape
It seems Server Caching (OutputCache or ResponseCache) is not possible in .net framework 4.7.2 Have to upgrade to Core, but thats a big task!